# Rendering multiple variants with Storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I am building my storybook documentation for a library I built with React and I am not finding a easy way to render multiple variants in the same page.

So, what I have so far is something like this

```
const Template = (args, { argTypes }) => <Title {...args} />

export const Primary = Template.bind({});
export const Success = Template.bind({});
export const Warning = Template.bind({});
export const Inverse = Template.bind({});
export const Default = Template.bind({});
export const Info = Template.bind({});
export const Danger = Template.bind({});
export const Disabled = Template.bind({});

Primary.args = {
  children: 'Primary',
  level: 3, // <- this can go from 1 to 5,
  as: 'h1', 
  variant: 'primary',
}

Success.args = {
  children: 'Success',
  level: 3, // <- this can go from 1 to 5,
  as: 'h1',
  variant: 'success',
}
```

etc...

This generates this:

[image]

and I am trying to achieve something like this when I render each variant:

[image]

How can I do something like that with Storybook?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can render multiple instance of Component inside a Story by using `decorators`

Sample code (should be similar for your code):

```
export const Primary = Template.bind({});
Primary.args = {
  primary: true,
  label: 'Button',
};

Primary.decorators = [
  () => {
    return (
      <>
        <Button {...Primary.args as ButtonProps} level={1} />
        <Button {...Primary.args as ButtonProps} level={2} />
        <Button {...Primary.args as ButtonProps} level={3} />
      </>
    );
  },
];
```

Output:

[image]

More [info](https://storybook.js.org/docs/ember/writing-stories/decorators#story-decorators), there are 3 level of `decorators`, it worth a read:

1. Story level
2. Component level
3. Global level